# How to create an addin within the existing windows application?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

There is a big windows application in which we also have WPF, I need to create an addin so that i can move my hige client to small addins. Problem is i need to pass commands or want to talk to other windows of the existing application from the addin. I have tried plugins which i have loaded through reflection. but how do i communicate to the other windows of the existing application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't communicate with other windows directly. If you need an architecture like this, have a look at [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) for instance. And for communication between modules/add-ins you either use some sort of events (Prism has EventAggregator) or you provide interfaces in a project common to all other projects, and use dependency injection like [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx) to provide modules with implementations of those interfaces. I know this is a very broead answer and you'll stil have to learn a lot, but your question is equally broad and there's just no way you can learn how to deal with large scalable applications in one-two-three. Or a couple of days/weeks.

Comment: Hi Stijn, This is a big solution which i was thinking will change the whole architecture. But still thanks a lot. it cleared me what i was thinking is a possible solution.